# Css selector for style and + not working

Tags: css, less, frontend

I want to change button style if the button is hidden.

Here are my sample code :

**HTML :**

```
<button class="first-button" resolved="" style="display: none;">Button</button>
<button class="second-button" resolved="">Button</button>
<button class="third-button" resolved="">Button</button>
```

**CSS :**

```
.first-button[style*="display:none"] + .second-button:not([style*="display:none"]) {
background-color: #ccc !important;
}
```

I tried in chrome, there nothing changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector failed because of the attribute-value you're looking for; in the `style` attribute; the *attribute* contains a space character `display: none;`, your attribute-selector did not (`[style*="display:none"]`).

If you fix that discrepancy it works perfectly:

```css
.first-button[style*="display:none"] + .second-button:not([style*="display:none"]) {
  background-color: #f90 !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="first-button" resolved="" style="display:none;">Button</button>
<button class="second-button" resolved="">Button</button>
<button class="third-button" resolved="">Button</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cxb9c9zm/).

Note, of course, that I did change the colour to `#f90`, rather than `#ccc`, for reasons of more-obvious visibility.

Incidentally given that specific selector it's worth noting that the `!important` flag is – almost certainly – entirely unnecessary.

Comment: i would eventually look for a single keyword such as  `.first-button[style*="none"] + .second-button:not([style*="none"])`or  to be more specific `.first-button[style*="display"][style*="none"] + .second-button:not([style*="none"])` ... now let's hope there is no chance to be facing uppercase from an oldish editor :)